# Calculating and inserting value into table column using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm a newbie to Rails. So pardon if this is a silly question.

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the Bank Balance and Cashbox balance in a Transaction. So this depends upon the type of transaction "Debit/Credit" and type of payment "Online Payment/Cheque/Cash". There is only one model involved and that is Transaction Model and transactions table. So this is what I'm doing,

transactions_controller

```
def create      

        @transaction = Transaction.create(transaction_params)

        @amount = transaction_params[:amount].to_f
        @cashbox = transaction_params[:cashbox].to_f
        @bank = transaction_params[:bank].to_f

        if transaction_params[:t_type] == "Debit"
            if transaction_params[:t_method] == "Cash"
                @cashbox -= @amount
                transaction_params[:cashbox] = @cashbox.to_s

            else
                @bank -= @amount
                transaction_params[:bank] = @bank.to_s

            end
        elsif transaction_params[:t_type] == "Credit"
            if transaction_params[:t_method] == "Cash"
                @cashbox += @amount
                transaction_params[:cashbox] = @cashbox.to_s

            else
                @bank += @amount
                transaction_params[:bank] = @bank.to_s

            end
        end

    if @transaction.save
        redirect_to @transaction
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:date, :notes, :t_type, :t_method, :amount, :paid_by, :paid_to, :cashbox, :bank, :house_id, :expense_for)
end`
```

Transaction Model

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

But when I submit the form containing all the values, the calculation part does't happen and rails inserts only the values submitted in the form.

How to calculate cashbox balance and bank balance on submit from the form  and store the updated values in the table?
Also, kindly suggest if there are any better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this functionality to the model and update object before rendering (if i understood you right). Now you never save the changes into the object.

Comment: Can you explain on how to update the object in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is confuse, let read more resful of rails.
- First: you can't save, after that create Transaction again.
- Second: you created transaction and below don't see updating that transaction should of course it be not changed.

Let try yourself:

```
def create      

    @amount = transaction_params[:amount].to_f
    @cashbox = transaction_params[:cashbox].to_f
    @bank = transaction_params[:bank].to_f

    if transaction_params[:t_type] == "Debit"
        if transaction_params[:t_method] == "Cash"
            @cashbox -= @amount
            transaction_params[:cashbox] = @cashbox.to_s

        else
            @bank -= @amount
            transaction_params[:bank] = @bank.to_s

        end
    elsif transaction_params[:t_type] == "Credit"
        if transaction_params[:t_method] == "Cash"
            @cashbox += @amount
            transaction_params[:cashbox] = @cashbox.to_s

        else
            @bank += @amount
            transaction_params[:bank] = @bank.to_s

        end
    end

    @transaction = Transaction.new transaction_params
    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to @transaction
    else
      render 'new'
    end
```

end

def transaction_params
    params.require(:transaction).permit(:date, :notes, :t_type, :t_method, :amount, :paid_by, :paid_to, :cashbox, :bank, :house_id, :expense_for)
end`

Comment: Hi @huyhoang.framgiavn, I've tried this before but the values in the views are not updated. It returns the same value I posted while submitting the form.

Comment: @user1690913 ok. I saw a bug at here. that is you using format :  transaction_params[:cashbox] = cashbox.to_s. Let instead all expresses have this type to   params[:transaction][:cashbox] = cashbox.to_s

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things in a bit of a muddle I think:

1) `if @transaction.save`

Here you're trying to save the transaction and only continuing if you do so successfully. Where is `@transaction` getting set up though? Presumably in some kind of `before_filter` but I suspect you don't need that in this case.

2) `@transaction = Transaction.create(transaction_params)`

Now you're creating, and saving to the database, a new `Transaction` object base on the parameters that are being submitted from the form (but only if it passes validation).

3) Then you do a load of work to calculate some parameters that appear to be transaction parameters. At this point though you've already created the transaction object with the parameters that were submitted. You add all these to the `params` hash which is predominantly used to pass web request parameters in (yes, you can use it for other things but I'd avoid doing that just yet).

Now, the most simple fix is probably to move your `Transaction.create` line to after all your params changes because then you'll be creating a transaction with the parameters you want. I wouldn't advocate that though. It seems like this code would be better moved to the Transaction model and have a method to apply the values to a transaction after you've built it.

(I'd also question if you've got your modelling quite right. You seem to be passing in a `@bank` value as part of the web request and then applying the value of the transaction your creating to it to give your bank value on the transaction. Of course, I'm not sure of your exact requirements but this seems like a potentially problematic approach. One for a different question perhaps).

Comment: Hi @Shadwell, to be precise, When I submit the form, I need to update the values of :cashbox and :bank to the new value( value after debit/credit from amount) and insert it into the table. Right now, the data submitted in the form is what is displayed in the view. Also can you precisely explain how to do this?

Comment: No, sorry, precisely explaining how to do that is way outside the scope of a question on here. I'd basically be writing your code for you.

Comment: No, I didn't ask you to write the code for me. I've ported the code to a new method in my Transaction model. How can I reference this method to print the updated value?